# How to build electron react app for Mac OS on Linux OS

Tags: reactjs, linux, macos, electron

I am new for electron framework and I dont have mac machine to build app for mac OS.
May I know how to build the electron react app for mac OS on Linux OS system.

Answer (score 0):

### With digital signature

To sign your app, you have to do it on MacOS.

### Without digital signature

If you don't require that your app is signed, you can achieve that with electron packager: https://electron.github.io/electron-packager/main/

You use this package like so:

```
npx electron-packager <sourcedir> <appname> --platform=<platform> --arch=<arch> [optional flags...]
```

So for example, running in root of your package directory:

```
electron-packager . --platform=darwin --arch=x64
```

Note that unsigned app will show security warnings when being installed.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [Conveyor](https://hydraulic.dev/), which is an alternative packaging tool that can do what you're asking (it can also create and sign Mac apps from Windows!).